# C Error: expression must have arithmetic or pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, struct, nodes, insertion

```
typedef struct node
{
    Record data;
    struct node *next;
}Node;

Node *head = NULL;

void addRecord(Record x)
{
    Node *previousNode = NULL;
    Node *newNode;
    Node *n;

newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
newNode->data = x;
newNode->next = NULL;

if (head == NULL)  // The list is empty
{
    head = newNode;
}
else       // The list is not empty
{
    n = head;
    while (n->next != NULL)
    {
        ***if (n->data < newNode->data && n->next->data > newNode->data)*** // Insertion Sort
        {
            // We have to put it between these 2 nodes
            newNode->next = n->next;
            n->next = newNode;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            previousNode = n;
            n = n->next;
        }
    }
    n->next = newNode;
}
```

}

I have this error in the code within the if function of the insertion sort. The program says that 'n' must have arithmetic or pointer type. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: I'm almost sure the error message you posted (pasted) is erroneous

Comment: What line are you getting error on? What is the definition of type Record?

Comment: The error is (MSVC) `error C2088: '<': illegal for struct`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator overload is not supported in C, so you cannot compare `Record` using `>` operator unless it is `typedef`ed to `int` or other aritimetic or pointer type.

To compare something like structures, define comparation function and use it.

Example:

```
typedef struct {
    int a, b;
} Record;

/*
return positive value if *x > *y
return negative value if *x < *y
return 0 if *x == *y
*/
int cmpRecord(const Record* x, const Record* y) {
    if (x->a + x->b > y->a + y->b) return 1;
    if (x->a + x->b < y->a + y->b) return -1;
    return 0;
}

/* ... */
    while (n->next != NULL)
    {
       if (cmpRecord(&n->data, &newNode->data) < 0 && cmpRecord(&n->next->data, &newNode->data) > 0) // Insertion Sort
        {
/* ... */
```